# CSS Outline error with Block Display

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a combobox in html and CSS, in which every item is on a separate line, and each line lights up blue when you mouse over it, like on Google. That much is easy. I have a `div` with links(`a`) in, and each link uses `display:block` in CSS to fill the whole `div`. Then I added a dotted outline to theone being hovered over, and that's where things went strange.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbR6K/).

You can see it working if you hover over the top link, but the others don't seem to show the outline... The second one down is just visible at the bottom, but the others aren't there at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I'm in IE8 on Windows XP

Comment: Interesting.. I'm in IE8

Comment: I see that outline around all elements, in Chrome and Firefox.

What version of what browser are you testing in, and on what OS?

Comment: @mori57 I'm in IE8 on Windows XP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp

"Note: IE8 supports the outline property only if a !DOCTYPE is specified."

If you're testing this in IE9, using Compatibility Mode, make sure that your Document Mode matches Internet Explorer 8 standards, not Quirks. If I switch mine to Quirks mode, the outline disappears.

Comment: Having a !DOCTYPE doesn't change the effect; I've tested it on a local page with one

Comment: Suggest you clear cache and give it a whirl again? I don't know, but when I start seeing oddities like that, I usually have to give IE a quick seat in the pants to get it to play nice again.

Comment: No joy. Incidentally, [here's](http://www.ar-t.co.uk/About2.html) the file in question. The search bar is what your looking at.

Comment: Hm. I'm still seeing a dotted outline, but very very faintly, because it's outside the border (which I believe is where it's supposed to appear, according to the spec), but I don't have native IE8, just IE9 in Compat. mode. Sorry I can't give you much more guidance on that... is there a particular reason you have to use outline, or can you give some other visual cue?

Comment: Is there another visual cue that does a similair thing? I wanted something similair to what happens when you hover over items in a `<select>` element.

Comment: Most select boxes I see only change the background color, which is a very obvious cue that you're over an element and ready to choose it. I don't know that I've seen a select box that only changes the outline... usually it combines some sort of border effect or background effect to make it obvious to the user that this item is the one they're picking. Other select lists either change the font weight of the hovered-over text, or add the text-decoration: underline to it... anything that makes an immediate impression of change of state should do the trick for most users.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll stick with changing colour then. Thanks.